# How to add 'filler' characters up to N limit to a variable length string using Excel / Sheets formulae?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets, string-manipulation

I have a list of strings (names / description text) that I need to add 'filler' characters to.

The maximum string length is 32 - for any text under that (in characters) I need to add special filler characters - up to that limit.

EG:

Original String - 30char - `ReallyLong String Name Example`

Revised String - 32char - `ReallyLong String Name Example**`

What is the best way to do this either with excel / sheets on it's own OR with a formula?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3):

Add the characters then cut to 32 length.

`=LEFT(CONCAT(A1,"********************************"),32)`

Comment: Nice one @Brian, to make it even tidier: `=LEFT(A1&REPT("*",32),32)`, you can leave out `CONCAT` as it serves no purpose in here, plus it's a function only available from office 365 insiders and office 2019 if I'm not mistaken. :)

Comment: @JvdV Cool ```Rept()``` function JvdV.  Then I can satisfy my OCD with ```=IF(LEN(A1)<32,A1&REPT("*",32-LEN(A1)),A1)```  Did not realize ```concat()``` might be limited. Hopefully at least the fully spelled out ```concatenate()``` is available to all users.

Comment: It certainly is available, but why a check for Len? It's irrelevant 